# how to count number of rising edges in a clock cycle using matlab code?

Tags: matlab, counter, simulink, clock

How do we count number of rising edges in a clock cycle using `MATLAB` code?
I have tried this-

```
 counter = o ;
    for (clock > 0)
    counter = counter +1;
    end
```

Comment: `for (clock > 0)` is not valid Matlab syntax. (look at `while` instead). Moreover, Matlab `for` loop are **static**, the iterator (`clock` in your case) is defined at the beginning of the loop and cannot be modified from within the loop, so if Matlab was accepting your syntax, it would run forever ...

Comment: Also I'm assuming that `counter = o` should be `counter = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code as discussed in the comments, but assuming that you have a signal that changes between two states, for example

```
clock = [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

then this simple expression will count the number of rising edges:

```
sum(diff(clock) > 0)
```

Without knowing more about the type of data that you are processing then it is difficult to provide a better answer, and indeed this will only work where every positive transition is considered a rising edge, i.e. there is no noise in the signal.

---

If you really want to use a `for` loop, then try this:

```
counter = 0;
for find(clock > 0)
  counter = counter +1;
end
```

But this will not count the rising edges, rather the number of instances where `clock > 0`, which could also be achieved using just `counter = sum(clock > 0)`. Note that in the for loop, if `clock` is a column vector then you will need to use `for find(clock > 0)'` instead of `for find(clock > 0)` (note the tick at the end of the line).

---

**UPDATE** to address your comment.

```
% Initialise clocks
x = [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0];
y = [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0];

% Initialise counter
count = zeros(size(y));
counter = 0;

% Loop through signals (note that x and y should be the same length)
for i = 2:numel(y)
  % Find rising edge on x
  if x(i - 1) == 0 && x(i) == 1
    counter = 0;
  end
  % Find rising edge on y
  if y(i - 1) == 0 && y(i) == 1
    counter = counter + 1;
  end
  % Store current value of counter for display
  count(i) = counter;
end

figure;

subplot(3, 1, 1);
stairs(x);
ylabel('x');

subplot(3, 1, 2);
stairs(y);
ylabel('y');

subplot(3, 1, 3);
stairs(count);
ylabel('counter');
```

This will give the following output:

[image]

Comment: i am dealing with a simple square pulse, for sum(diff(clock) > 0);

Comment: i also want the counter to store the last count, and save it and then again set it to 0

Comment: @anuki, by *simple square pulse*, do you mean like at the top of my answer? I'm not sure what you mean by *store the last count, and save it and then again set it to 0*. Can you clarify a bit, perhaps with an example (you might want to edit your question)?

Comment: yes exactly the same square pulse as described by you. and what i mean is i am actually having two clocks. x = [111110000011111000001111100000] and y = [1010101010101010101010101010] now i want to count the number of edges of y on the rising edges of x. that's why after counting the no. of rising edges of y for 1 pulse of x. i want to pass the counted no. of edges of y to a comparator. and hence on the 2nd rising edge of x i want to start counting from 0 again. may be this is clear

Comment: @anuki, I have added an example to solve your problem, but please note that we are not a code-writing service. This is a very simple implementation which makes many assumptions so may not be entirely suitable for your situation, but should give you something to work from.

Comment: but what if clock is continous and the length is not defined, for example clock is from a phase lock loop source,then how do we define the length

Comment: @anuki I've never used Matlab in a real-time setting. If you want to do real-time processing then you have a lot of work to do before you are ready to start processing the clock signal. Matlab is generally used offline where the data is recorded and the length is known.

Comment: If you want to know how to read and process a signal in real time, then you should ask another question about that, and I would be quite interested to see what the answer is. Out of interest, how are you reading the clock from the PLL?